# How to avoid 'failed to find a valid digest ..' in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

Just created a react app and after updating a component the chrome console shows me:

> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for
>   resource 'http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js' with computed
>   SHA-256 integrity 'M5yTiqE22UudSQqI2cuMzsLFb18jt0y1oeDRYKgEQYo='. The
>   resource has been blocked.

Strangely enough IE does refresh the page without this error (finally IE does something good...)
How can I resolve this? Guessing might be some webpack config issue?

Comment: not sure if it can help you: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1231#issuecomment-266233702